# Prove that $uN\{0,1,2,\dots,m-1\}\equiv N\{0,1,2,\dots,m-1\}\pmod{mN}$, when gcd$(mN,u)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions, coprime

Let $m,N\in\mathbb{N}_2$, and consider modulo $mN$. Let $u\in\{1,\dots,mN-1\}$ such that gcd$(mN,u)=1$. I want to show that the following two sets are equal, where order is unimportant;
$$uN\{0,1,2,\dots,m-1\}\equiv N\{0,1,2,\dots,m-1\}\pmod{mN}.$$
(For completion, we take $cA\pmod{n}\equiv\{ca\pmod{n}:a\in A\}$)

For example; let $m=6$, $N=24$, and let $u=5$, which satisfies gcd$(mN,u)=$gcd(144,5)$=1$. Then we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
5\times 24\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}\equiv 5\{0,24,48,72,96,120\} \equiv&\: \{0, 120, 240,360,480,600\}\\
\equiv&\: \{0,120,96,72, 48, 24\} \equiv 24\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}\pmod{144}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I've been struggling with this for a few days now. It appears simple, but I just keep getting lost in knots of logic. I could also just be missing something obvious... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with ideals (ring theory)?

Comment: @BillDubuque I am familiar, as far as a module in my undergrad on ring theory went. I suspect I should be able to follow along, as long as it's not too abstract. Thanks!

Comment: Can you work on the case of $N=1$? Is that equality obvious?

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't think that's too obvious why, but in the context I am using these in we actually have $N\neq1$ - I will make that edit, thanks.

Comment: I meant for you to consider that case first. To me, that's the crux of the problem, because you can factor out the value of $N$ from each of these terms.  IE if $ ui \equiv j \pmod{m}$, then $uiN \equiv jN \pmod{mN}$. So if you prove that we have a bijection for $N=1$, then we have a bijection for all $N$.

Comment: @CalvinLin ahh I see. I was getting caught in my own context, but yes you're right. If I can show it for $N=1$ then it would extend, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating all the numbers as elements of $\mathbb{Z}/mN\mathbb{Z}$ is more convenience. The set $S=N\{0,1,2,\dots,m-1\}$ is the set of all multiples of $N$ in $\mathbb{Z}/mN\mathbb{Z}.$ Let the map $f(x) = ux$ be the function from $S$ to its image $uS = uN\{0,1,2,\dots,m-1\}.$ The image of $f$ is a subset of $S$ since if $x$ is a multiple of $N,$ then so is $ux,$ therefore $uS \subset S.$ $f$ is bijective because it is invertible with the map $x \mapsto u^{-1}x,$ so $S$ and $uS$ has the same size, and therefore they are the same.